# Can I restrict User from saving files from not supported version of excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I create excel application that have password protection on sheets. What I want to do is restrict user from saving file when they open using older version of excel that does not have password protect feature. Older than 2003.
Is this achievable. 
Thanks on advance.

Comment: Can't you version check within workbook_beforesaving? the cancel parameter can be set to true to avoid saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a code to check version of Excel and it cancel the save if the version is older :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim xl_version As Integer
    xl_version = VBA.Val(Application.Version)

    If xl_version < 11 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Your Excel version is too old"
    End If

End Sub
```

List of Excel version :

8: "Excel 97"

9: "Excel 2000"

10: "Excel 2002"

11: "Excel 2003"

12: "Excel 2007"

14: "Excel 2010"

15: "Excel 2013"

16: "Excel 2016"